# What is wrong with this code? Compile Error: Expected: Identifier

Tags: vba, ms-word

Totally new to coding.  Found this to try for what I thought would be a simple/easy project but I keep getting the above error every time I run it. Help! Thank you in advance.

```
Sub InsertFutureOrPastDate()
  Dim strNumberOfDays As String

  ' Input the number of days you want to insert from today to the future or past date.
  strNumberOfDays = InputBox("Please input the number of days you want to insert", "future or past date", "Input here.For exemple,input 1 to insert the date of tomorrow")
  ' Insert the future or past date according to the inputed number of days
  If strNumberOfDays <> "" Then
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(Date + strNumberOfDays, "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")
  End If       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps a piece of code meant for Word that you tried in Excel? Put it in Word VBE and it'll work. If you want to use it in Excel, you will have to find a way to put the text where you want it. Perhaps something like this:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Date + strNumberOfDays, "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")
```